# How to display a JSON data in extjs or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4

I have a JSON data with format like this:

```
{
 key1: val1,
 key2: val2,
 key3: val3,
 key4: val4,
 ..
}
```

I want to build a table or grid to display it like this:

```
_______________
|keys | values|
|-------------|
|key1 | val1  |
|key2 | val2  |
|key3 | val3  |
|key4 | val4  |
---------------
```

Which component in Extjs or jQuery should I use? And how to match my json data into this table?

Could you give me some code as a sample?

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate HTML that renders a table based on the data in the JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the example in Ext js

```
            Ext.onReady(function(){
            var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
              fields: ['keys', 'values' ],
              autoLoad: true,
              data:  [ 
                {  "keys":"Key1", "values":"Value1"},
                {  "keys":"Key2", "values":"Value2"},
                {  "keys":"Key3", "values":"Value3"},
                {  "keys":"Key4", "values":"Value4"}

              ]
            });   

                          var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                      frame: true,
                      title: 'Database',
                      width:300,              
                      store: Grid1Store,
                          columns: [
                               {text: "Keys", dataIndex: 'keys'},
                              {text: "Values", dataIndex: 'values'}
                          ]
                                  });

            });
```

if you want to load a json file change grid store code like these

```
    var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: ['keys', 'values' ],
   autoLoad: true,
  proxy:{
     type:'ajax',
          url:'something.json',
          reader:{
           root:'users'
           }
    }

   });
```

Comment: The format of json data you are using is not as same as what I am using. How can I transfer mine to yours?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Grid Plugin seems like the tool you need. http://www.trirand.com/blog/.

In [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page, in the "Loading data" section, you should find a working example for displaying a JSON object as a grid.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Implement like this in your Json Call.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
 $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
     var items = [];
     $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        alert ( " key=" + key + " and val = " + val + "" );
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yow will find a lot of JQuery plugin or a simple one like

```
var data = {
 key1: 'val1',
 key2: 'val2',
 key3: 'val3',
 key4: 'val4' 
};

for(var i in data){
    $('#datatable').append('<tr><td> '+ i +' </td> <td> '+data[i]+' </td></tr>');       
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/370/